# Increment with integer

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I want to Use `Progressbar1.Increment` but I wanna use Integer but the problem is that the maximum value of integer is over 100 so i want to set the `Integer.Maxvalue` to 5 but it got an error when I tried using `Integer.MaxValue(5)` and `Integer.MaxValue = 5`, So I need to the the `Maxvalue` to 5

PS:I use Vb 2005 Express Editon*

*I`m a student what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue isn't with the progress bar.  Your issue is that you're creating random numbers that are larger than you require.

Use one of the overloads of `Random.Next()`. This code will return an integer x; 0 <= x < 5

```
Dim number As Integer = Random.Next(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim progressBar As New System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
    progressBar.Maximum = 150
    progressBar.Minimum = 100
    progressBar.Step = 1
    progressBar.Increment(5)
```

This works fine for me in VB NET

Comment: umm max of integer is approximately 2,147,483,647 since integer is a random number selection i wanna increment with progressbar like +3,+1,+4,+5,+2

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the max value of integer. That is fixed, permanent, and immutable. You won't be able to do it, no matter how much you'd like to.

Instead, you have to set the maximum value of the progress bar that uses this integer. You do that by setting the progressbar's .Maximum property. This will make sure that no integer larger than your desired maximum is ever used with the progressbar.